# Norm is not multiplicative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the book of Introduction to Analysis by William R. Wade, on page 273, it is said that:

> Although the norm is not multiplicative, the following fundamental inequality can be used as a replacement for the multiplicative property in most proofs.

And then the Theorem on Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality follows. However, what does it  exactly mean that the norm is not multiplicative, and how is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the standard Euclidean norm, although the following explanation applies to most norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let the normed space be $V$. By multiplicative, it means for all $x,y \in V$, $|\langle x,y \rangle| = ||x||\cdot ||y||$, which is not true in general (for instance, take two standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$). We have to use an inner product as it doesn't always make sense to take a product of two vectors in an arbitrary normed space.

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows $|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq ||x||\cdot ||y||$, so we do get an estimate on the inner product. If you follow the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz you'll see we get equality iff $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, i.e. $x$ is a scalar multiple of $y$.

Comment: I think you meant "linearly dependent".

Comment: In case of linear dependence, you get only the equality $\big| \langle x,y \rangle \big| =  ||x||\cdot ||y||$ with absolute value.  To get the equality you mentioned, you need one of $x,y$ a nonnegative scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Ah, yes. I seem to be all over the place today